# How to get screen dimensions for iPhone using openCV?

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, computer-vision, objective-c++

I was trying to get screen width and height of iPhone using OpenCV. But not able to get exact results.

Here is the one I used, but giving wrong results.
I was new to OpenCV. So I was not sure using it in correct way.

```
cv::Rect screenRect = cv::Rect(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
```

How do I get `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` of the application frame?

Thanks in Advance.,

@Gralex After using the solution you gave. I got the result like this...

[image]

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

@interface OpenCVWrapper() <CvVideoCameraDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CvVideoCamera *videoCamera;
@end
@implementation OpenCVWrapper

#pragma mark - initializers
- (instancetype)initWithParentView:(UIImageView *)parentView {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        parentView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:parentView];
        self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
        self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
        self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
        self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
        self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = false;
        self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
        [self.videoCamera start];

    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods
- (Mat)applyCannyAlgorithm:(int)threshold input:(Mat)input {
    Mat cannyCVResult;
    Canny(input, cannyCVResult, threshold, threshold*2);
    return cannyCVResult;
}

- (Mat)changeGrayAndApplyBlur:(Mat)input {
    Mat greyCVImage;
    cvtColor(input, greyCVImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(greyCVImage, greyCVImage, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);
    return greyCVImage;
}

- (void)detectAndDrawBoundaries:(Mat)cvMat {
    Mat cvImage = cvMat;
    Mat blurImage = [self changeGrayAndApplyBlur:cvImage];
    Mat cannyResult = [self applyCannyAlgorithm:80 input:blurImage];

    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    findContours(cannyResult, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) {
        cv::Rect rect = boundingRect(Mat(contours[i]));
        rectangle(cvImage, rect.tl(), rect.br(), Scalar(255,0,0), 4, 8, 0);
    }

    cv::Rect upperRect = cv::Rect(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width*2, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
    cv::Rect lowerRect = cv::Rect(0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width*2, UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.height);

    rectangle(cvImage, upperRect.tl(), upperRect.br(), Scalar(0,255,0), 8, 8, 0);
    rectangle(cvImage, lowerRect.tl(), lowerRect.br(), Scalar(0,0,255), 8, 8, 0);
}

#pragma mark - CvVideoCamera Delegate Methods
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image {
    [self detectAndDrawBoundaries:image];
}

@end
```

Comment: What did you get for iPhone 5s?

Comment: I got iPhone 6s

Comment: What size did you get on iPhone 6s?

Comment: @Gralex updated code. I'm using objective-c++ wrapper in swift project.

Comment: for iPhone 6s - (x = 0, y = 0, width = 750, height = 2668) and the code is cv::Rect upperRect = cv::Rect(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width*2, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height*2);

Comment: But camera give you different resolution. Try to print `cvMat.size()`, pretty sure it will be different size.

Comment: Yes got different results
cv::Rect upperRect = cv::Rect(0, 0, cvMat.size().width, cvMat.size().height);
(x = 0, y = 0, width = 1080, height = 1920)

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru if you wanna project screen points to camera capture, don't forget about you mode is `AspectFill`. Also pretty common mistake. It will be small offset on x or on y coord.

Comment: But they are not screen dimensions. Those will be image size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197388/discussion-between-gralex-and-krishna-chaitanya-bandaru).

Answer (score 0):

You get size in points. To get in pixels, you need to multiply by `UIScreen.mainScreen.scale`

```
cv::Rect screenRect = cv::Rect(0, 0, 
  UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width * UIScreen.mainScreen.scale, 
  UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height * UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
```

Comment: I tried this but still got issues. Updated screenshot in question.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru Seams this problem not in code where you get values. Can you provide code how you get this image on the screen?